# AJAX-транспорт Script

Tags: ajax, javascript

привет.
Покажите работающий пример технологии AJAX-транспорта через теги Script.Можно с примитивной серверной частью.
[Нашел вот здесь статью ,но нету примера](http://javascript.ru/ajax/transport/script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делать было нечего, решил помочь рабочими примерами, как и просили. Пример состоит из четырех файлов, при этом условно будем считать, что у нас два сервера и мы осуществляем между ними кроссдоменные запросы.
**Сервер 1** это сервер предоставляющий доступ к списку городов/стран итп.
**Сервер 2** это клиент запрашивающий эти списки.
Зачем все это нужно- по соображениям безопасности браузер не позволяет так называемые кроссдоменные запросы в XMLHttprequest, и все ниже изложенное служит способом обойти это ограничение.
Выбор города демонстрирует способ получения данных от другого сервера.
Тест длинных запросов показывает как один длинный запрос разбивается на много маленьких, а серверная часть собирает его и обрабатывает как одно целое.

Сервер 1. Файл getCity.php

```
<?
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
$data=explode("\n", file_get_contents("city.dat"));
if (preg_match("/^\\w+\$/", $_GET["land"])){ 
    foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
        $tmp=explode("|", $v);
        if ($tmp[0]==$_GET["land"]) {
            $script=<<<HEREDOC
                function x(){
                    var arr=$tmp[1];
                    if (targetToScript.children[0]) targetToScript.removeChild(targetToScript.children[0]);
                    var sel=document.createElement("select");
                    for (var i in arr){
                        var opt=document.createElement("option");
                        opt.innerHTML=arr[i];
                        sel.appendChild(opt);
                    };
                    targetToScript.appendChild(sel);
                };
                x();
HEREDOC;
            echo $script;
            break;
        };
    };
}
?>
```

Сервер 1. Файл city.dat

```
Russia|["Дефаульт-Сити", "Ленинград", "Соль-Устинск"]
FRG|["Кельн", "Берлин"]
```

Сервер 1. Файл longQuery.php

```
<?
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
$part=(int) $_GET["part"];
$total=(int) $_GET["total"];
$data=@unserialize(file_get_contents("tmp.tmp"));
if (empty($data)) $data=Array();
if (sizeof($data)<$total) {
    $data[$part]=$_GET["text"];
    file_put_contents("tmp.tmp", serialize($data));
    echo "callback_next();";
} else {
    echo "callback_end(\"".implode("", $data)."\");";
    unlink("tmp.tmp");
};
?>
```

Сервер 2. Файл testScriptCrossdomenQuery.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <script>
    function getCity(city){
        var sc=document.createElement("script");
        sc.src="http://localhost/getCity.php?land="+city;
        document.head.appendChild(sc);
    };
    function callback_end(text){
        alert(text);
    };
    function callback_next(){
        i++;
        var sc=document.createElement("script");
        sc.src="http://localhost/longQuery.php?part="+i+"&total=10&callback=callback&text="+i+",";
        document.head.appendChild(sc);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="country" onchange="getCity(this.value);">
        <option value="">Выберите город...</option>
        <option value="Russia">Россия</option>
        <option value="FRG">Германия</option>
    </select>
    <div id="targetToScript">
    </div>
    <input type=button style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:300px" value="Тест длинных запросов" onclick="i=0; callback_next();" />
</body>
```

Поизучайте этот пример, он мне кажется минимально простым и понятным, и при этом рабочим и самодостаточным.
При этом я пошел на небольшое упрощение: по определению callback надо передавать как параметр скрипту php.

Comment: За старания спасибо.Буду разбираться

Answer (score 2):

[Пример с использованием jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809053):

Клиент:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.site.com/jsonp.php?callback=?','firstname=Jeff',function(res){
    alert('Your name is '+res.fullname);
});
```

Сервер:

```
<?php
$fname = $_GET['firstname'];
    if($fname=='Jeff')
    {
          //header("Content-Type: application/json");
         echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'fullname' : 'Jeff Hansen'}" . ')';

    }
?>
```

[Вот ещё есть подробная статья на эту тему](http://sprain.ch/blog/2010/07/07)